# Problema ao fazer requisição para API usando XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em JavaScript puro. (Sim eu quero fazer, mesmo sabendo das limitaçoes rsrsrs)
Porem eu não consigo acessar a API, pois gera o seguinte erro quando eu faço algum `request` pra API.

Segue anexo do erro e do meu código:

Erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
var minhaPromisse = function () {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY", 'MINHA-KEY-DA-API');

    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                reject('Erro na requisição')
            }
        }
    }
});
}

minhaPromisse()
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente inserir mais esse header após o que você já insere antes de enviar a requisição:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: Não funcionou, o erro persistiu.

Comment: Eu editei minha resposta agora a pouco, por acaso testou com o código de agora ou com o que estava antes?

Comment: testei ambos, o antigo e esse novo

Comment: Uma dúvida, por acaso você está executando esse script por onde? Pois para esse tipo de requisição funcionar é necessário ser realizada através de um servidor local. Se só está executando a página direto em um navegador não vai funcionar.

Comment: estou rodando no live-server